# Jquery Show/Hide div when dynamic div has height greater than 1000px

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic div on the middle of a page which contains dynamic content.

```
<div class="wp-main">
Some dynamic content...
</div>
```

I would like another div `wp-filter` to fade-in only when the `wp-main` has a height of greater than 1000px and user has scrolled past 50% of its height and fade-out otherwise or when the user scrolls anywhere else on the page outside of `wp-main`.

I am looking for a Jquery solution.

I have tried this code which works for the main window but it is not bind to `wp-main`.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>1000)
     {
        $('.wp-filter').fadeIn();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.wp-filter').fadeOut();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($("#wp-main").height()>1000)
     {
        $('.wp-filter').fadeIn();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.wp-filter').fadeOut();
     }
 });
```